# How to get the name of the .har file using firefoxdriver

Tags: selenium, firebug, webdriver

I'm using firebug webdriver to capture netstreams to a .har file.  I will write a parser to get the relavant info from the file but to automate this process i need to know what the name of the .har file is.  The default filename is host+date.  Is there a getName api for this file?

thanks!

- chris

Answer (score 0):

None that I know of. In my projects I simply list all har files from directory and pick the one with newest creation date. It always works.